# Refactor a link and an image

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

I have to write an link with an image inside. Instead of explaining, here's the code I have now:

```
<c:if test="${userSession.loggedUser eq null and company.image != null}">
    <a onclick="${rich:component('loginPanel')}.show()">
        <img src="/download.do?hash=#{company.image.hash}" />
    </a>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${userSession.loggedUser eq null and company.image == null}">
    <a onclick="${rich:component('loginPanel')}.show()">
        <img src="${request.contextPath}/img/icons/logo_default.jpg" />
    </a>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${userSession.loggedUser ne null and company.image != null}">
    <a href="company.xhtml?${company.name}">
        <img src="/download.do?hash=#{company.image.hash}" />
    </a>
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{userSession.loggedUser ne null and company.image == null}">
    <a href="company.xhtml?${company.name}">
        <img src="${request.contextPath}/img/icons/logo_default.jpg" />
    </a>
</c:if>
```

This code looks awful - there are two exact links with two exact images but combined in all possible combinations. Is there a better way?
Is there a way to avoid c:if - it created tables?

**Update**: Bozho proposes:
You can replace `<c:if` and `<a` with `<h:outputLink rendered="#{..}"`. Apart from that I don't see any other optimization.

But it doesn't work. This does not render correctly:

```
<a href=>
<h:outputLink rendered="#{..}
<h:outputLink rendered="#{..}
</a>
```

(the image is outside the anchor)

This does render fine:

```
<h:outputLink value=>
<h:outputLink rendered="#{..}
<h:outputLink rendered="#{..}
</a>
```

, but it always adds href and in two of the cases I don't want href when rendered.

**Update2**: I also had them combined 2 by 2:

```
<c:if>
  <a href...>
    <c:if><img...></c:if>
    <c:if><img...></c:if>
  </a>
</c:if>
<c:if>
  <a onclick...>
    <c:if><img...></c:if>
    <c:if><img...></c:if>
  </a>
</c:if>
```

This also does not render correctly - the `<a` does not surround the images for some crazy reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<c:set var="isLoggedIn" value="#{userSession.loggedUser != null}" />
<c:set var="showPage" value="company.xhtml?#{company.name}" />
<c:set var="showLogin" value="javascript:${rich:component('loginPanel')}.show()" />
<c:set var="hasImage" value="#{company.image != null}" />
<c:set var="companyImage" value="/download.do?hash=#{company.image.hash}" />
<c:set var="defaultImage" value="#{request.contextPath}/img/icons/logo_default.jpg" />

<a href="#{isLoggedIn ? showPage : showLogin}">
    <img src="#{hasImage ? companyImage : defaultImage}" />
</a>
```

This can be shortened as follows (will only be a bit nastier to read/interpret quickly):

```
<c:set var="showPage" value="company.xhtml?#{company.name}" />
<c:set var="companyImage" value="/download.do?hash=#{company.image.hash}" />
<c:set var="defaultImage" value="#{request.contextPath}/img/icons/logo_default.jpg" />

<a href="#{userSession.loggedUser != null ? showPage : 'javascript:${rich:component(\'loginPanel\')}.show()'}">
    <img src="#{company.image != null ? companyImage : defaultImage}" />
</a>
```

Comment: `href="#"` doesn't work, because it brings the page to the top. `href="#tag"` also fails, because for some reason it refreshes the page.

Comment: OK, then use `javascript:` pseudoprotocol in `href` instead of `onclick`. I updated the example.

Comment: This now works. Never thought of that. Looks a lot better. Thanks. Btw, `<c:set` should always have `value` attribute.

Comment: Not necessarily. The body can also represent the value. I have changed all though.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `<c:if` and `<a` with `<h:outputLink rendered="#{..}"`.
Or `<c:if` with `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{..}">` (for the sake of being more jsf-ish)

In order to reduce duplication, you can create a separate page:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{condition}">
    <a onclick="${rich:component('loginPanel')}.show()">
        <img src="#{imgSrc}" />
    </a>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and then `<ui:include>` with proper `<ui:param>`. the switch between onclick/href can be done by another parameter, and conditionally displaying one of `<a` tags.

Comment: See updated post. Also I want to avoid duplication. And now there's a lot of it.

Comment: I thought of that too, but I'm wondering if it can be done without one. I have a lot of cases like this and the page clutter would be substantial.

Comment: @Mihail Stoynov it's about 4 snippets that have only little similarities. It's fine retaining them as they are.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create link depends on 3 parameters: test, href and src. You can create your own tag.

**edited:**
Or next solution: You can notice that always will be generate only one link so I would change if to switch and do something like this:

```
<c:set var="loggedUser" value="${userSession.loggedUser eq null}" />
<c:set var="isCompanyImage" value="${company.image != null}" />

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${loggedUser && isCompanyImage}">
        <c:set var="aPart">onclick="${rich:component('loginPanel')}.show()"</c:set>
        <c:set var="imgPart">/download.do?hash=#{company.image.hash}</c:set>
    </c:when>
    ...
</c:choose>

<a ${aPart}><img src="${imgPart}" /></a>
```

Comment: I want a simple and elegant solution.

Comment: what doesn't work with facelets? Encountered some exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
<c:set var="companyImage" value="/download.do..." />
<c:set var="defaultImage" value="logo_default.jpg" />

<c:if test="${userSession.loggedUser == null}">
    <a onclick="${rich:component('loginPanel')}.show()">
        <img
            src="#{company.image != null ? companyImage : defaultImage}"
            alt="logo"
            width="84"
            height="42"
            class="th_user"
        />
    </a>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${userSession.loggedUser != null}">
    <a href="companyUrl.jsf">
        <img
            src="#{company.image != null ? companyImage : defaultImage}"
            alt="logo"
            width="84"
            height="42"
            class="th_user"
        />
    </a>
</c:if>
```

It's not pretty, because the image is still there twice with all its attributes, but I wasted too much time on this. If anyone thinks of anything better, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try:

```
<h:link value="#{}" onclick="..." rendered="#{not empty sessionScope.loggedUser and not empty company.image}">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{requestScope.contextPath}/img/icons/logo_default.jpg" />
    <f:param name="company" value="#{company.name}" />  
</h:link>
```

What i'm trying to show you is the ,  and  Tag. Just play a little bit with it :) Should be fine to solve your problem.